# .htaccess: Some Rewrites working while others not

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's a snippet of my .htaccess file:

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule spanish-vocabulary-bible http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  RewriteRule books/svb http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for spanish vocabulary bible
  RewriteRule svb http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for emails
  RewriteRule emails http://peppyburro.com:2082/cpsess5562708231/frontend/paper_lantern/mail/pops.html [NC,L]
```

Of these, all rules except the second one are working just fine. I am going crazy figuring out what might be wrong here. The only thing I can guess is that somehow any rule that involves a subfolder structure as the alias (e.g. `books/svb`) is not working. If you notice the ones that do work, they're all without a "/" – svb, emails, spanish-vocabulary-bible. Does this mean anything or just a coincidence? I have tested using several other names and combinations and the results are consistent.

Update: Based on the first answer below, I changed the second rewrite to this:

```
RewriteRule books/svb/?$ http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
```

It is still not working.

Update 2: I just changed `books/svb` to `tome/svb` in the second rule and it worked. But there are two problems with this:

1. I need it to be books and not tome or anything else,
2. The redirect is transparent, i.e. it shows the redirected URL in the address bar; I want the redirected URL (the one with POST data) to be hidden.

On anubhava's request below, here's a dump of my entire .htaccess file. It's quite long, I am afraid:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

  <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|visionutils|Facebot|Facebook [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Rewrite all dictionary words to a prerendered dictionary page
    RewriteRule ^dictionary/.* http://service.prerender.io/http://www.peppyburro.com/dictionary/ [P,L]
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|visionutils|Facebot|Facebook [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Rewrite all dictionary words to a prerendered dictionary page
    RewriteRule ^conjugator/.* http://service.prerender.io/http://www.peppyburro.com/conjugator/ [P,L]
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|visionutils|Facebot|Facebook [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://www.peppyburro.com/$2 [P,L]
  </IfModule>

  #<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|PDF)">
  #  ForceType application/pdf
  #  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  #</FilesMatch>

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  #RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.peppyburro.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for blog feed
  RewriteRule feed blogs/feed/burrorss [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for blog admin (old)
  RewriteRule admin blogs/wp-admin [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for books
  RewriteRule spanish-vocabulary-bible http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  RewriteRule books/svb http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for spanish vocabulary bible
  RewriteRule svb http://peppyburro.com/books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L]
  #Rewrite rule for emails
  RewriteRule emails http://peppyburro.com:2082/cpsess5562708231/frontend/paper_lantern/mail/pops.html [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Proper MIME types for all files                                            |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Audio
    AddType audio/mp4                                   m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg

  # JavaScript
    # Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways):
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript                      js jsonp
    AddType application/json                            json

  # Video
    AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

  # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
    # however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
    # following fonts.
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
    # https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
    AddType     image/svg+xml                           svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                                    svgz

  # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash               swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                ico
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | ETag removal                                                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Since we're sending far-future expires headers (see below), ETags can
# be removed: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags.

# `FileETag None` is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag

  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

FileETag None

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers (for better cache control)                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following expires headers are set pretty far in the future. If you don't
# control versioning with filename-based cache busting, consider lowering the
# cache time for resources like CSS and JS to something like 1 week.

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | GZip Compression (for faster page transfers)                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# GZip Compression
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf application/x-font-opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/otf font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're not using anchors in your regex and 3rd rule with `svb` is overriding `books/svb`.

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^spanish-vocabulary-bible/?$ books.php?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule (?:^|/)svb/?$ books.php?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^emails/?$ http://peppyburro.com:2082/cpsess5562708231/frontend/paper_lantern/mail/pops.html [NC,L,R]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Why do I need an anchor if there's no regex involved? I am just trying to redirect `books/svb` to `books?bb=spanish-vocabulary-bible`. There's no variable in the first argument. Am not sure I understand the answer.

Comment: Besides, it's only the second rule that's not working. All others are redirecting fine, but you have suggested adding `/?$` to every single one of them.

Comment: Also, how can a rule on `svb` override one on `books/svb`? Note that I haven't used the caret sign.

Comment: The file is in my root directory as usual and is the only htaccess I have. And yes there are a bunch of other rules but none that could interfere with this one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the 3rd question. The URL I am trying is: *http://www.peppyburro.com/books/svb*

Comment: No it isn't. But neither are emails, svb, or tome all of which are redirecting successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117600/discussion-between-anubhava-and-thelearner).

Comment: Could you please help me with one tiny question related to this?

Comment: I needed to. It wouldn't allow me to place a bounty on a question with an accepted answer. I will accept it once again as soon as the bounty opens in another 9 minutes.

Comment: Okay I opened the bounty but now it says I must wait for 23 hours before awarding it. But don't worry, it is yours. :)

Comment: Not worried at all knowing you are at it. Thanks so much :)